# how to change div contents based on drop down change dynamically using mysql php

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

how to change div contents based on dropdown change dynamically using  mysql php ?

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT vendor_info.`vender_id`, vendor_info.`vender_name` , products.`vender_id` , products.`prod_id` , products.`prod_name` FROM vendor_info,products WHERE vendor_info.`vender_id` =products.`vender_id`");

                                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
                                                 { 
                                                echo  $v_id=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$row['vender_id']);
                                                  $sql_b=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from `vendor_info` where `vender_id`= '$v_id'");
                                                ?>
                                                  <option value="<?php echo $v_id ?>"><?php echo $row['vender_name'];?></option>
                                             <?php  
                                               }
                                               ?>

                                             </select>
                                          </div>

                                         </div>


                            </div>

                            <hr>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <?php 
                                            echo $que ="select * from products where vender_id='$v_id'";
                                                   $query=mysqli_query($conn,$que);
                                                   while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                                             ?>

                                     <div class="<?php echo $v_id ?> box">You have selected <strong><?php echo $row['prod_name']; ?></strong> so i am here
                                           <?php }?>
                                    </div>
```

in second div i want to change content based on drop down selection. i put code in second div for fetching data according to id of select box. but this code not work.

Answer (score 0):

You an load the content of the second div using AJAX. In your first div make onchange call to a function Eg: `<select onchange='loadDiv(this.value);'>`
This will call a function `loadDiv(value)`, there you can send a ajax request to a file which will fetch the data based on the value of the First select box. Then you can simply load the content using CSS selector `$('#secondDiv).html(result)` Here the result is the drop down content which is returned based on the first select box value. Hope you understand this !